# How to fix gbak database restore error involving RDB$ADMIN role?

Tags: firebird

When restoring a database using gbak on Firebird 2.5 I get the following error:

> gbak: restoring privilege for user SYSDBA
>   gbak: restoring SQL role: RDB$ADMIN
>   gbak: ERROR: attempt to store duplicate value (visible to active transactions) in unique index "RDB$INDEX_39"

This index is one the `RDB$ROLES` relation, which has one row `RDB$ADMIN`. How can this error be fixed?

Comment: Try gfix -utility: http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/gfix-dbverify.html

Comment: As far as I know this problem can occur if the restore was done with a Firebird 2.1 or earlier gbak, or if a Firebird 2.5 backup was restored to Firebird 2.1, backed up and then restored on Firebird 2.5. What does `gbak -z` say about its version?

Comment: Thank you for the help But I need a solution to the problem rather than the cause.

Comment: I still need to know which gbak version you used to 1) backup the database and 2) restore the database.

Comment: Is there still no real workaround on this? Seem to be experiencing same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the role **RDB$ADMIN** and run **gbak** again.